# Deletar um registro do firebase auth

Tags: java, android, firebase

Preciso deletar um registro do Firebase Auth, estou usando o seguinte código:

```
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    user.delete().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

        }
    });
```

Porem está dando um erro:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task
>   com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.delete()' on a null object
>   reference

Alguém sabe o que estou fazendo de errado ou como eu deleto um registro do Firebase Auth?

Comment: `user`certamente é nulo. Você não tem um usuário logado com essa instância do FirebaseAuth. Se você quiser deletar um usuário específico e não o próprio usuário conectado (que nem um adminstrador/superuser) use o Firebase Console.

Comment: Eu quero deletar o usuario q está corrente, por exemplo... após ele sair de uma pagina de validação de login, sem ter validado utilizando um código que é enviado por sms(tudo pronto até aqui), o usuário dele é deletado do banco, pois ele não terminou seu cadastro.

Comment: Entendi. Mas seu FirebaseAuth não tem nenhum usuário, talvez ele nem mesmo tenha sido criado em primeiro lugar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muito provável que o user esteja retornando `null`.

A causa dele estar retornando `null` pode estar ligado a Autenticação. Você está autenticando o usuário?

Faça uma validação na sua `Activity` conforme exemplo abaixo:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    updateUI(currentUser);
}
```

Adicione o `task.isSuccessful()` no seu método user.delete() para validar:

```
user.delete().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "User account deleted.");
            }
        }
});
```

**Fontes:**

[Get Started with Firebase Authentication on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start)

[Gerenciar usuários no Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users?hl=pt-br)

Comment: Esse metodo "updateUI" não existe! estou usando o Firebase Auth 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'

Comment: Que estranho, é pra existir, veja se não falta algum _import_.